# How to filter form input data with json data in plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, rest

I am stuck in little confusion how to fetch the specific result if I type title name in input formfield.Below is code that I have tried. I ll appreciate it.Thanks

index.html file

```
<form method="POST">
 <input type="text" id="searchName" class="form-control" placeholder="Lorem name">
<button  onclick="userAction(event)" class="search-icon"><img src="images/icon.png" alt="submit"></button>
  </form>

<ul id="list">

</ul>





JavaScript File
const list = document.getElementById('list');
const searchName = document.getElementById('searchName').value;

const userAction = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(todos => {
    todos.forEach((todo) => {
    if(todo===searchName){
      const li = document.createElement('li');

      li.innerHTML = li.innerHTML = `${todo.userId} ${todo.id} ${todo.title} ${todo.completed}`;

      list.appendChild(li);
    }
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: Does your API allow you to submit the search as a parameter so that it only returns the data the matches that search string? `fetch('http://jsonserver.com?search=searchName')` for example. That would be better. Then you could just iterate over the returned data knowing that it's correct.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for your reply. Can you please write some so, I can understand it.Thanks

Comment: I have just updated my code as well.

Comment: If your JSON service doesn't process URL params there's no point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#searchName` has no value on page load and you are not updating the value inside the function, thus if condition fails.

You should take the search value inside the function.

```js
const list = document.getElementById('list');
const userAction = async (event) => {
  list.innerHTML = ''; //clear the content on each click
  event.preventDefault();
  const searchName = document.getElementById('searchName').value.trim();
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(todos => {
    todos.forEach((todo) => {
      if(searchName == todo.title){
        const li = document.createElement('li'); 
        li.textContent = `${todo.userId} ${todo.id} ${todo.title} ${todo.completed}`;
        list.appendChild(li);
      }
    });
  })
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">
 <input type="text" id="searchName" class="form-control" placeholder="Lorem name">
<button  onclick="userAction(event)" class="search-icon"><img src="images/icon.png" alt="submit"></button>
  </form>

<ul id="list">

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for you response Mamun. I just run code snippet when I entered  delectus aut autem into input field then its not displaying data on related to this but showing all the json data.Please help.Thanks

Comment: @Yasir, you have to check the *title* property of the object like `if(searchName == todo.title){...`, updated the answer, please check:)

Comment: I have just updated my code as well.Mistakenly, I missed one point..

Comment: Can you please edit your code snippet.So it would be easier for me to understand..

Comment: @Yasir, but if I put *delectus aut autem* in the input I get *1 1 delectus aut autem false*...

Comment: One Last thing. how to replace the new result with the previous one because its started creating a list. I don't want a list just to replace the result.Thanks

Comment: @Yasir, simply clear the content on each click with `list.innerHTML = '';`, I have updated the answer, please check:)